# Modified Euler method

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I am revising the modified euler method and would appreciate some help with this question:

The equation is $$y'=\frac{2}{x}y+x^2e^x, y(1)=0$$

Use modified euler method to calculate $y(1.1)$ taking $h=0.1$ (working to $4$ decimal places)

Where do i start?

any help is appreciated thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$k_1=h\,f(x_n,y_n)$$
$$k_2=h\,f(x_n+h,y_n+k_1)$$
$$y_{n+1}=y_n+\frac 12 (k_14k_2)$$
where
$$f(x,y)= \frac2x+x^2e^x$$